# How to analyse averaged data (when raw data is not available)

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

I need to analyse the results of a messaging trial where the value of interest the the click through rate (CTR) on social media ads. I tested 8 ads and a control and I have the CTR for each one (e.g. message one had a CTR of 1%, message two had a CTR of 2%).

The issue is I don't know if just using an ANOVA will be ok because I literally just have nine figures (the CTRs) and not a full dataset with multiple rows that the ANOVA would use to take an average and then compare that average to see if there is a statistically significant difference.

Can anyone weigh in on how I can understand whether there is a difference between my groups?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean by your full dataset. Could you show an example of what it looks like? I'm not sure why this would be a problem based on the dataset alone.

Comment: Hiya - so I dont have a dataset with a row for each person who saw the message with a 0 if they then didnt click on it and a 1 if they did. I have the click through rate for everyone who saw the message (e.g. 1% of people who saw message one clicked, 2% of people who saw message two clicked). I dont have any individual level data, only the summary (the click through rate).

My data literally looks like this:
Message 1 = 1% CTR
Message 2 = 2% CTR
Message 3 = 3% CTR
Message 4 = 2% CTR
Message 5 = 3% CTR
Message 6 = 4% CTR
Message 7 = 3% CTR
Message 8 = 1% CTR
Message 9 = 2% CTR

Comment: It just sounds like your data is in either wide or long format and needs to be reformatted accordingly. If you already have the grouping factors coded, that shouldn't be a problem. Reference: https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Comment: Hi - that's not really my issue. Maybe if I used a metaphor? It's like if you have three classes of kids sit a test and you want to figure out if any class is statistically better than the others but all you have is the average test score for each class, not the scores for each student (that you could then run through an ANOVA where the mean would be calculated and then compared). In this situation where you have three mean values how would you figure out whether there is any statistically significant difference between them?

Comment: No significance test is possible without the raw data.